# Polymer 2: routing from views and custom elements

Tags: javascript, url-routing, polymer-2.x

I'm migrating an existing Polymer-based application to Polymer 2, and one thing the [Polymer 2 upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade) is annoyingly silent about is how to update the routing code to work with the updated `app-route` and all its "routing encapsulation" system.

With Starter Kit 1, we had the `page()` function, so an event handler that wanted to change the current route simply ran `page("/new_page")`.

With Polymer 2, I've discovered several different approaches to affect route changes:

## 1. Create a custom event handling setup for your application:

#### Main

```
<app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>
<app-route route="{{route}}" pattern="/:page" ...></app-route>

...

ready() {
  super.ready();
  window.addEventListener('change-route', e => this.set('route.path', e.detail));
}

...
```

#### View

```
...

handleGoToOtherPage() {
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('change-route', { detail: '/new_page' }));
}

...
```

Cons: this is really cumbersome, especially the event dispatching.

## 2. Use Javascript History API

[(as documented in `app-route`)](https://github.com/polymerelements/app-route#integrating-with-other-routing-code)

#### View

```
...

handleGoToOtherPage() {
  window.history.pushState({}, null, '/new_page');
  window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'));
}

...
```

Cons: I don't mind using just `pushState()`, but pushing a new state is not enough as `app-location` doesn't actually monitor the window location, so you need to "let it know" that it should re-read it. the result is code which is even more cumbersome than option 1, though thankfully I don't need to setup custom event handlers in the main app.

## 3. Use `<iron-location>` to push location changes

#### View

```
...
<iron-location id="location"></iron-location>
...

handleGoToOtherPage() {
  this.$.location.path = '/new_page';
}

...
```

Cons: I can only update the `path`, `query` and `hash` separately, and if I update only one, I may get into trouble. Also, look hacky...

## Summary

Which method do you think is *The Right Thing(tm)*?

Do you have another method that is better?